# How can I hide and protect devices in Dolphin (and other places in KDE)?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin

On most KDE file open dialogues and Dolphin, my devices (mounted and otherwise) are displayed as options. Clicking these convenient takes you to their mounted path (and mounts them first if they aren't already).

This is great, except...

[image]

All of these have unmount options. Thankfully not all of them work.

- 111.8 GiB is my dmraid0 root disk
- nerf is a mdadm RAID10 array so volume disks are inappropriate (and unmounting any is outright dangerous). Clicking one of the paused nerf entries really upsets KDE.
- steam1 and jeff are just JBODs but I never want to be able to unmount it from here. I have things cross mounted into and from them. They're system disks.

So is there a way to manage this list of devices?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check the `Hide 111.8 GiB Hard Drive` checkbox, and dolphin will not display that drive any more.